# Android test switch app under test

Tags: java, android-testing

How to change the project under test for an android test project without re-create a new test project in Eclipse (or ADT boundle) environment?

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit the project under test in the Build Path: Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects -> add the new project you want to test (must be in your workspace) 
ant the go to your test project and edit the Manifest.xml:

```
android:targetPackage="the package of the new app under test" />
```

That's all. 
Start to test the new app